# Precedence of cast in c#

Tags: c#, operators

What is the precedence of a cast in c#?  For example in the following code, will z be less than or equal to two?

```
double x = 4.5;
double y = 2.1;
double z = (int) x / y;
```

Comment: well..did you try it out?

Comment: Yes, I tried it out, but I thought it would be handy if I put my code into a question.  I found the question that @Steve referenced was too ambiguous, and that a better example would make it clearer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The cast beats all binary operators for binding. Hence (int)x / y means ((int)x)/y.

On the other hand, you should always prefer *readable* code to *clever* code, so since you don't know you should write the following instead:

> ((int)x) / y

Note that brackets are free, and make your code more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Less than:

```
using System;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        double x = 4.5;
        double y = 2.1;
        double z = (int) x / y;
        Console.WriteLine(z);
    }
}
```

See here: http://ideone.com/fhg5ai

Answer (score 1):

`z` will be less than two:

```
    double x = 4.5;
    double y = 2.1;
    double z = (int) x / y;
    Console.WriteLine(z); //1.9047619047619
```

Your code is really doing this: `((int)x) / y`, which may or may not be your expected output.